# axios.get returns empty array in data

Tags: reactjs, axios, mongodb-query

I am trying to implement a cart in react js using mongo
This is the front end request

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(state === null) {
        setLogin(false)
    }
    else {
        setLogin(true)
        if(state.cart !== null) {
            
            axios.get('http://localhost:5000/cart',state.cart)
            .then(res => {
               console.log("res data is : " , res );
            })
        }
```

**state.cart** is an array of product ids from the token which is then used to fetch product docs in the backend.

This is the backend route code :

```
router.route('/cart').get((req,res) => {
const pids = req.body._id
Product.find({"_id" : { $in : pids}}, function(err, result){

if(err){
    res.send(err)
}
else{
    // console.log(result)
    res.json(result)
  }

})

})
```

When I console.log(res) in axios it returns
**data: Array(0)**, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Here the data array is empty but Insomnia is giving me a proper array like this :

```
[
{
  "_id": "60c7566b5e9943a056f83af2",
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Coffee",
   "description": "This coffee uses both Robusta and Arabica beans. A delicacy for 
    connoisseurs.",
   "cost": 10,
   "img": "img/coffee.jpg"
},
{
   "_id": "60c7578a5e9943a056f83af3",
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Muffin",
   "description": "A muffin nom nom :)",
   "cost": 2,
   "img": "img/muffin.png"
 },
{
   "_id": "60c757bf5e9943a056f83af4",
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Biscuit",
   "description": "The best chocolate sandwich biscuit in town.",
   "cost": 4,
   "img": "img/biscuit.jpg"
}
]
```

So I don't understand how the data is empty

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe your backend is expecting a key of `_id` on the `req.body`. However, you're not currently creating this key in the axios request.

As per the [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config#:%7E:text=only%3A%20Stream%2C%20Buffer-,data,-%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20%27Fred%27%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%0A%20%20//%20syntax), you need to add a `data` key to the "options" object:

```
axios.get('url', {data: {_id: [/* array of product ids */]}});
```

You can confirm this by adding `console.log(req.body)` in the backend code.

Comment: This made no difference to it

Comment: What did the console.log reveal?